# Where can I find a paper by Grose, 1983?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, specific-reference

I would like to read the Paper "Orifice flow at low Reynolds number" by Grose published in 1983. It seems to be cited a few times, also in recent publications.

The best meta-data on the publication that I have found so far is this: https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/biblio/5216286

I could not find the referenced journal, nor a DOI or anything really that would help me to find a resource. Does anybody now more about the Journal "J. Pipelines, Netherlands" or can point into the right direction? Also newer publications on the same topic are welcome.

Comment: Not available due to copyright. I know, it's ridiculous! https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=grose&id=mdp.39015029613505&view=1up&seq=15 Maybe you can gain access though. Page 207.

Comment: Try a library close to you https://www.worldcat.org/title/journal-of-pipelines/oclc/173735945

Answer (score 2):

From Web of Science I get:

ORIFICE FLOW AT LOW REYNOLDS-NUMBER
By:GROSE, RD (GROSE, RD)

JOURNAL OF PIPELINES
Volume: 3
Issue: 3
Pages: 207-214
Published: 1983

ELSEVIER SCIENCE BV, PO BOX 211, 1000 AE AMSTERDAM, NETHERLANDS

Not available on-line through my institution.

Go ask your local, friendly research librarian about getting a copy.

Comment: @Peter - well, either it is not in digital form (yet?), or it isn't part of my institutions subscription since we don't do pipelines. Frankly it is still a bit weird that people expect everything to be available on the web, but that is mostly showing my age and experience looking through dusty tombs in the basements of libraries...

Comment: It is available online because I googled it and found it. Didn't see the text but the search engine found it therefore it must be digitized. The problem is that greedy institutions block access even to content that noone ever reads. Very annoying problem, especially with older publications.

Comment: @Peter - well, if nobody really reads it, perhaps the effort to digitize isn't worth it? But it used to be that if it wasn't in the basement stacks you'd ask a librarian and wait weeks to months for a badly-Xerox'd copy to show up. That option still exists, although the copy is digital (often badly-scanned) now. (Yes, not online does not mean not available through my institution.)

Comment: +1 for "ask your librarian"

Comment: @JonCuster - thanks. The publisher being Elsevier is new information. This might help.